# Connect USB Drive to HyperV with Debian as a Guest OS

Tags: windows, debian, hyper-v, debian-stretch

Does anyone know how to connect USB Drive to HyperV with Debian as a Guest OS? Passthrough mechanism (Enhanced Session Mode) only works with Windows as a Guest OS.

Please help me how can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use USB REDIRECTOR, cheap and usefull 
It's multiplatform.